# как при помощи php сжать pdf файл

Tags: php, pdf

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли средствами php сжать pdf-файл?
На сайт происходит загрузка файлов пользователями и некоторые файлы слишком тяжелые. (ограничения на вес загружаемых файлов не предлагать)
В сети есть онлайн ресурсы по сжатию PDF и их работа по сжатию на мой взгляд не плоха (почти 10Мб зажал до 6-7Мб).

Смотрю сейчас TCPDF (где то было указано, что этот класс может сжимать, но на оффсайте ничего подобного пока не нашел.

**Дополнение**
Некоторые файлы могут состоять из отсканированных документов, т.е. файл без фотографий и картинок, но сам состоит из изображений содержащих текст. Логично было бы распознать и по новой пересоздать PDF, но качество сканов низкое и распознать без потерь не выйдет (потери недопустимы).

**UPD**
Кто работал с **TCPDF**, подскажите, есть ли в нем возможность:

1. сжимать PDF, если ДА, то КАК?
2. парсить PDF в HTML (получение и текста и картинок), если ДА, то КАК?

Т.к. не нахожу ответа на свой вопрос смотрю в сторону парсинга PDF в HTML и обратной сборки, но предварительно сжимать весь контент файла. (возможно это и бредовая идея)

Comment: В общем случае - никак. Только с потерей качества

Comment: @ Андрей NOP, можете подсказать способ сжатия с потерей качества? Я бы попробовал, может не так велика потеря.

Comment: @medvedev а если использовать библиотеки bz2 или zip для компрессии?

Comment: @Андрей NOP, я так понимаю, что это архивирование, хотелось бы обойтись без этого. К тому же bz2 - "для её включения вам следует скомпилировать PHP с указанием директивы --with-bz2[=DIR]"

Comment: @defrag, подозреваю, что pdf уже использует сжатие внутри и не пожмется. Это как сжимать jpg или mp3...

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, есть такое. Но там как повезет, у меня на одном pdf  файле объемом 4,2 Мб "выйгрыш" маленький - после компрессии bzip2 (или winrar-ом) 4,1Мб, а другой pdf 29Мб - после компрессии стал 4,5Мб

Comment: @medvedev, без сторонних библиотек это нетривиальная задача. Навскидку гуглится, например, это: https://developer.ilovepdf.com/docs/guides/compress-pdf-api

Comment: @medvedev если никакие "компрессирующие" библиотеки не подключены, то может подойдет вариант с вызовом внешней утилиты компрессии через shell_exec например.

Comment: @Андрей NOP, Ваша ссылка возможно и могла бы решить проблему, но это получается загрузка файлов через API на "забугорные" сервера, а это запрещено. Может есть какие-то библиотеки? Пока гугл не смог помочь.

Comment: Возможно, если важен только текст - можно конвертировать pdf в текст - тогда все хорошо сожмется.

Comment: Таки на выходе что должно получиться? Тоже pdf?

Comment: Надо: пользователь грузит **pdf -> pdf сжимается на стороне сервера -> сохраняется** или на сервере или загружается в файловое хранилище. Последний пункт уже не суть важен, но **на входе и на выходе PDF** . P.S.: изображения могут быть в файле и их выкидывать нельзя из него.

Comment: Размер PDF состоит из разметки самого PDF и текста внутри + размер прикрепленного контента (изображений, файлов, скриптов). Сжать получится только текст, контент обычно уже с сжатых форматах, либо не сжимается вовсе. Отсюда вывод - сжимайте просто файлы при загрузке на сервер в обычный gz, tar.gz или zip, храните так, и при отдаче файла разжимайте. http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzfile.php - обычный gz, дополнительных модулей не потребуется. Вы решите 90% решаемых проблем и сохраните себе нервы на оставшихся 10% нерешаемых проблем

Comment: @wirtwelt, к сожалению руководство не разрешает архивировать. Файл должен быть всегда доступен в виде PDF. Печально, если сжимается только текст. Но как тогда онлайн сервисы по сжатию PDF сжимают файл состоящий из сканов? Исходный размер файла: **1.191** Mb
Новый размер файла: **0.991**Mb (при среднем сжатии) и **0.268** Mb (при сильном сжатии)

Comment: Сжимать надо только для хранения. Загружаете файл, сжимаете, кладете на сервер. При обращении к URL файла перенаправляете с помощью .htaccess+ModRewrite запрос на php-скрипт, который берет файл, разжимает и отдает пользователю не сжатый файл. Для пользователя файл останется PDF, на сервере будет хранится только gz. Сжатие на сервисах как точно работает - не знаю, не знаком.

Comment: @wirtwelt, для хранения хотим использовать сторонние хостинги, чтоб разгрузить свои сервера. Выбранный хостинг принимает форматы: JPG PNG GIF BMP TIFF PSD PDF. Ваше предложение вполне разумно, но конкретно в данном случае, слишком много ограничений.

Comment: http://fx-files.ru/archives/1863

Comment: @wirtwelt, ps2pdf - попробовал, еще до вашей ссылки. Не сжатые файлы отлично сжимает, а вот те что нужны (состоящие из сканов, видимо сжаты по умолчанию при создании) всего на =+/- 100 кб.  а вот как консольные команды из php передавать и исполнять - никак не разберусь. (не факт, что результат будет лучше)